# Titanium - how to send view to another page?

Tags: javascript, view, titanium

I am using titanium studio for android. I am going to use `ScrollableView`, and I can't because `ScrollableView` can only be added to a window. How to send view to another page for use `ScrollableView`?

Comment: A ScrollableView can be added to a view as well. Could you provide some example code to demonstrate what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

ScrollableView can be added to view. if view need to be passed to next page you can pass it as arguments.

As best practice. I recommend you to pass the data instead of views. And construct views in open event of next page.

```
var nextPage = Alloy.createController("nextpageController",{ views : [view1,view2,view3] }).getView();

nextPage.open();
```

> In nextPage.js

```
var args = arguments[0];
$.scrollableView.views = args.views;
```